# What is the speed of electrons in a transistor?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, electronics

What is the average speed of an electron in a [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) transistor, and how can you calculate this?

I've heard people throw terms such as "drift velocity" and "Fermi velocity" around, but I've never gotten a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first chapter of Sze's classic Physics of Semiconductor Devices, one can find:
(1) in low electric fields, the drift velocity of carriers is proportional to the electric field strength (section 1.5 in the 2nd edition).  It then gives a number of approximations, depending on the primary scattering mechanism. 
(2) in high field regions, nonlinearities come into play (such as impact ionization), and things get even more complex. 
Bottom line - it all depends on the device material, doping, fields. Calculating from first principles would be a challenge.
But, read Sze (or equivalent semiconductor device physics book), and at least get an idea of which regime your particular problem is in.

Comment: Agree.  Perhaps the OP can get a better answer if he or she can let us know a little more about the problem: where is arises, why the interest, what region of the device ...